# Invalid free when yielding a temporary with a string field from a coroutine

Tags: c++, string, c++20, c++-coroutine

I'm using C++20 coroutines to implement procedures for my application. Procedures run until they have a message to report to the application, at which point they suspend until the application resumes them. Each message contains some text stored in a `std::string`.

Here's my procedure definition (`procedure.hpp`):

```cpp
#ifndef PROCEDURE_HPP
#define PROCEDURE_HPP

#include <coroutine>
#include <string>

struct Message {

    std::string value;

};

struct Procedure {

    struct promise_type {

        Message message;

        Procedure get_return_object() {
            return {std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)};
        }

        std::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept {
            message = {"Coroutine started"};
            return {};
        }

        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept {
            message = {"Coroutine finished"};
            return {};
        }

        std::suspend_always yield_value(Message message) {
            this->message = message;
            return {};
        }

        void unhandled_exception() {}

        void return_void() {}

    };

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;
    
};

#endif
```

And here's a working example of how to use them (`main.cpp`):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "procedure.hpp"

Procedure run() {
    // NOTE: message is an lvalue
    Message message{"message lifetime spans co_yield"};
    co_yield message;
}

int main() {
    auto procedure = run();
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "[Message] " << procedure.handle.promise().message.value << std::endl;
        if (procedure.handle.done()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            procedure.handle.resume();
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile and run this, I get the following output (which is expected):

```
$ g++-12 main.cpp -fcoroutines
$ ./a.out
[Message] Procedure started
[Message] message lifetime spans co_yield
[Message] Procedure finished
```

My compiler is GCC 12 on macOS:

```
g++-12 (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0
```

However, if I change the definition of `run` so the message yielded is a temporary (in `main.cpp`):

```cpp
Procedure run() {
    // NOTE: message is a temporary
    co_yield {"message is a temporary"};
}
```

Then the program crashes with an invalid free:

```
$ g++-12 main.cpp -fcoroutines
$ ./a.out
[Message] Procedure started
[Message] message is a temporary
a.out(15267,0x115cd8e00) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe306c05b50: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(15267,0x115cd8e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

As best as I can tell via debugging, the invalid free occurs during the destruction of the message's `value` field. This is very unexpected to me since I have not done any memory management myself beyond `std::string` does, and I copy the message during the yield.

The crash doesn't occur if the `value` field has some other type (e.g. an integer). It also doesn't occur if I yield the value directly (instead of wrapping it in the `Message` type).

What's going on here? How can I resolve this so I can safely yield a temporary?

Comment: `this->message = message;` I find this code dubious. You're having to explicitly use `this` explicitly because you decided to name two variables the same. It'd be better if you just avoid that by using better variable names.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see why you might not like it as a stylistic choice, but explicitly using `this` is valid and is unrelated to the issue (renaming the variables changes nothing).

Comment: I don't get any exception, native or not, however `run` is implemented, in Visual C++ 2022 with /std:c++20. And see it that compiler is a lot more fussy about memory abuse out of the box than it was years ago. But of course that's not proof the code is well defined.

Comment: Coroutines are new enough that you might want to mention your compiler (and version) at the end of the question (in case it's a compiler bug or otherwise compiler-dependent).

Comment: Good point, thanks! I just added my compiler (GCC 12.2.0) to the question.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug - the GCC forums say that handling temporaries was a common problem. Try it on 13.x, your code works both ways without trouble with GCC 13.1 on Godbolt.

Comment: @HerrJoebob Yes, I just did and that was it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who pointed out that it could be a compiler issue! After updating to the latest version of GCC (13), I no longer have an issue.